# jQuery's val() is not working on a hidden field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a hidden field in my page like so:

```html
<hidden id="tsDaySchedule01" value="7.50"></hidden>
```

When I try to access it with the following code, the alert returns blank:

```js
alert($("#tsDaySchedule01").val());
```

Now when I use `attr("value")` like below, it works without issue:

```js
alert($("#tsDaySchedule01").attr("value"));
```

Lastly, I would like to point out we have other *non*-hidden text fields within the page that work without issue using `val()`.

I would like to have a better understanding as for what is going on here. Does anybody have an explanation?

Comment: Where did you found this `hidden` tag ? oO

Comment: @Brewal the framework is a tag based language that typically converts the elements to their proper format, the problem had to do with me removing the namespace for the framework and forgetting to change the field. Thanks Everyone.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`<hidden/>` isn't a valid HTML element. If you're wanting a hidden input you'd use:

```html
<input type="hidden" />
```

jQuery's `.val()` method only works on `input`, `select` and `textarea` elements. To get this to work for you, change your `<hidden/>` element to:

```html
<input type="hidden" id="tsDaySchedule01" value="7.50" />
```

Comment: And `<select>` ;) Any form element in other words

Comment: Thanks James, it was an error on my end to use <hidden rather than input type="hidden". Thanks for catching that for me.

Answer (score 1):

[**.val()**](http://api.jquery.com/val/) method only works with text-box type of element  `input` and `textarea` elements.

you should use

```
<input type='hidden' id="tsDaySchedule01" value="7.50">
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you need to use :

```
<input type='hidden' id="tsDaySchedule01" value="7.50">
```